# What is the meaning of 'I am sorry to jump you like this'?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I heard a seemingly unusual usage of **jump** in the movie *Michael Clayton*:

> Michael Clayton: I need a loan. I need 80 grand.
>
> Marty: I thought you were done with all that.
>
> Michael: It's not the cards. It's the restaurant.
>
> Marty: 80,000?
>
> Michael: I'm sorry to **jump** you like this. I've been trying to meet you alone for two weeks.

Apparently **jump** here means *to surprise* or *to trouble the other person on short notice*. I can't find this usage in dictionaries. Though I was able to find definitions possibly related to this usage in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jump):

> to act, move, or begin before (something, such as a signal)
>
> - jump the green light
>
> to leave hastily or in violation of contract
>
> - jump town without paying their bills

What does **jump** mean exactly in the movie?

Comment: Since **jump** is transitive in the sense that Jason describes, we can say **get jumped**.  *Why is he all bloody?  --He got jumped.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per The Free Dictionary, [**jump**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/jump) is being used (figuratively) as slang for *ambush*:

> *v. tr.*
>
> **3** *Slang* To spring upon in sudden attack; assault or ambush: *Muggers jumped him in the park.*

In other words, Michael is apologizing for springing the request for money on him suddenly and unexpectedly, as somebody would do if they were ambushing and robbing someone.

You can't find it in regular dictionaries because it's slang that hasn't yet become used often enough.

Comment: Interestingly, I am actually quite familiar with this usage. In the past I have filed a police report about being jumped by bullies in school... So the line in the movie is a figurative usage of a figurative usage?

Comment: @L.Moneta Yes, it's a figurative use of a slang term. ;) (The line could as easily have been, "*I'm sorry to ambush you like this . . .*")

Comment: "You can't find it in regular dictionaries": you definitely can; it's "3a" under transitive verb in the Merriam-Webster link in the question. The sense of "to attack" is hundreds of years old [according to the Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/jump); it is informal but it's well-established.

Comment: @Miles *Jumped* ***on*** *him* is semantically different than *jumped him*. It doesn't have the same sense as the slang phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford You're looking at the intransitive example, I think. The transitive usage doesn't have "on". [Here's an example from a book written in 1890](https://books.google.com/books?id=LdmEAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22jumped%20him%22&pg=PA295#v=onepage&q=%22jumped%20him%22&f=false). [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/jump) and [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/jump_1?q=jump) dictionaries both have "jumped him" examples. The assertion that this is "new slang" that isn't in dictionaries is baseless.

Comment: @Miles No, it's not about being transitive of intransitive. I could be in a room full of people and suddenly "jump on someone." Yes, I might surprise them, and, yes, I might even assault them. But that's *not* the same specific meaning as sneaking up on somebody at night in a dark alley and ambushing them. The slang term conveys a different sense, even though some of the words in its description are the same.

Comment: @JasonBassford Fine, don't read my comments. If you'd click the links you'd see examples like "thieves jumped the old man as he walked through the park" which is 100% in line with your "not in dictionaries" definition. Your answer would be fine if you dropped the last sentence.